# Simple hello world non blocking MPI

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, nonblocking

I am practicing a simple non-blocking "Hello world" program with [this website](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-send-and-receive/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Status  status;

    int size, rank, data;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank>0) {
    MPI_Irecv(&data, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 0,  MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);

      std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " has received message with data " << data<< " from rank " << rank - 1
              << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Hello from rank " <<rank << " out of " << size<< std::endl;

    data=rank;

    MPI_Isend(&data, 1, MPI_INT, (rank + 1) % size, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I have a couple of problems: the first one is `(rank + 1) % size` does not make sense to me. I expect this to be just `rank+1` rahther than `(rank + 1) % size`. But, when I delete `%size`, the code doese not run. The second ambiguty I have is the result of this particular code which is :

```
#PTP job_id=12493
Rank 3 has received message with data 21848 from rank 2
Hello from rank 3 out of 4
Hello from rank 0 out of 4
Rank 2 has received message with data 22065 from rank 1
Hello from rank 2 out of 4
Rank 1 has received message with data 22043 from rank 0
Hello from rank 1 out of 4
```

I have defined data to be equal to rank, but it seems it throws something random. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** The main issue in your code (and likely) the reason data displays random values is the use of `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Isend` without the call of `MPI_Wait` (or `MPI_Test`).

[MPI_Irecv](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Irecv.html) and [MPI_Isend](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Isend.html) are nonblocking communication routines, therefore one needs to use the [MPI_Wait](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Wait.html) (or use [MPI_Test](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Test.html) to test for the completion of the request) to ensure that the message is completed, and that the data in the send/receive buffer can be again **safely** manipulated.

Let us imagine that you send an array of ints using `MPI_Isend` without calling `MPI_Wait`; in such case you are not really sure when you can safely modify (or deallocate the memory of) that array. The same applies to `MPI_Irecv`. Nonetheless, calling `MPI_Wait` ensures that from that point onwards one case read/write (or deallocate the memory of) the buffer without risks of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) or inconsistent data.

During the `MPI_Isend` the content of the buffer (*e.g.,* the array of ints) has to be read and sent; like-wise during the `MPI_Irecv` the content of the receiving buffer has to arrive. In the meantime, one can overlap some computation with the ongoing process, **however this computation cannot change (or read) the contend of the send/recv buffer.** Then one calls the `MPI_Wait` to ensure that from that point onwards the data send/recv can be safely read/modified without any issues.

In your code, however you call:

```
MPI_Irecv(&data, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 0,  MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
```

without calling `MPI_Wait` afterwards. Moreover, you change the content of the buffer *i.e.,*  `data=rank`;. As previously mention this can lead to **undefined behavior**.

You can fix this problem by either using [MPI_Recv](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Recv.html) and [MPI_Send](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Send.html) instead or by calling `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Isend` followed by `MPI_Wait`. Semantically a call to `MPI_Isend()` followed by a call to `MPI_Wait()` or a call to `MPI_Recv` followed by `MPI_Wait()` is the same as calling `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`, respectively.

> I have a couple of problems: the first one is (rank + 1) % size does
> not make sense to me. I expect this to be just rank+1 rahther than
> (rank + 1) % size.

To explain you the reasoning behind that expression let us think about your code with 4 processes, with ranks ranging from 0 to 3.

Process 1, 2 and 3 will call :

```
MPI_Irecv(&data, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 0,  MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
```

- Process 1 expects a message from process 0;
- Process 2 expects a message from process 1;
- Process 3 expects a message form process 2;

then all four processes call (let us replace the formula (rank + 1) % size, accordingly):

```
MPI_Isend(&data, 1, MPI_INT, (rank + 1) % size, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
```

- Process 0 sends a message from process (0 + 1) % 4 -> 1;
- Process 1 sends a message from process (1 + 1) % 4 -> 2;
- Process 2 sends a message from process (2 + 1) % 4 -> 3;
- Process 3 sends a message from process (3 + 1) % 4 -> 0;

So `(rank + 1) % size` is used as a trick so that when you reach the last rank it returns back the rank of the first.

All this to build the following pattern of recv/send message `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0.`

As you might have noticed `MPI_Recv` and `MPI_Send` are called 3 and 4 times, respectively. And even though you did not experienced any issue regarding this, commonly, not performing the same number of `MPI_Recv`/`MPI_Send` calls might cause deadlocks. This can be avoid if instead of using `(rank + 1) % size` you use just `rank + 1` and filter out the last processes from calling the `MPI_Isend`, as follows:

```
if(rank + 1 < size)
  MPI_Isend(&data, 1, MPI_INT, (rank + 1) 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
```

This means that Process 3 will not send a message to Process 0, but that is okey since Process 0 does not expect to receive any message anyway.

**A Running Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Status  status;

    int size, rank, data;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank>0) {
       MPI_Irecv(&data, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 0,  MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
       MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
       std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " has received message with data " << data<< " from rank " << rank - 1
              << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Hello from rank " <<rank << " out of " << size<< std::endl;
    data=rank;

   if(rank + 1 < size){
       MPI_Isend(&data, 1, MPI_INT, (rank + 1) 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    }
    MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
With 4 process a possible output:

```
Hello from rank 0 out of 4
Rank 1 has received message with data 0 from rank 0
Hello from rank 1 out of 4
Rank 2 has received message with data 1 from rank 1
Hello from rank 2 out of 4
Rank 3 has received message with data 2 from rank 2
Hello from rank 3 out of 4
```

Comment: Great answer! awesome!

Comment: a hell of an answer